# How can identify element by using UIAutomatorviewer for mobile native app when we don't any unique attribute of the element

Tags: android-uiautomator

I am beginner in mobile automation testing and I want to learn how to identify element uniquely when element don't have any unique attribute.

Answer (score 1):

The simples answer is "you can't". You have to identify it to the best of your capabilities.

If you previously know the app you are testing (most people are making tests specific for one app) then you can use the index property to your advantage.

If you don't you can only do an heuristic with as many properties you know about the object you are trying to identify.

Check uiAutomatorViewer (in sdk-folder/tools) to see the layout currently visible on your screen (UiAutomator sees exaclty the same).
Check [UiObject](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/support/test/uiautomator/UiObject.html) and [UiSelector](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/support/test/uiautomator/UiSelector.html) classed to see which properties you can access.

If you have any more specific questions just say it :)